# 1.11.2 Minecraft server crashes when player tries to join/ping server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I'm trying to set up a 1.11.2 Minecraft server on a local machine, but it crashes every time a player tries to join or ping the server. I've also noticed that when it starts, there are a couple of warnings that I've never seen before and don't really understand

Startup text:

```java
[10:24:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.11.2
[10:24:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[10:24:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[10:24:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[10:24:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 (file:/home/admin/Documents/Minecraft_Servers/captiveMinecraftII/server.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Aug. 04, 2020 10:24:54 A.M. io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent <clinit>
INFO: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability.
[10:24:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Using epoll channel type
[10:24:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[10:24:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[10:24:55] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 31%
[10:24:56] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (2.004s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
```

This is the error when a player tries to join:

```java
Aug. 04, 2020 10:26:20 A.M. io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext exceptionCaught
WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to access address of buffer
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.read(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.doReadBytes(EpollSocketChannel.java:678)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.epollInReady(EpollSocketChannel.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe$3.run(EpollSocketChannel.java:755)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:380)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:268)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `server.properties` file and set `use-native-transport` to `false`

Source: https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/unable-to-access-address-of-buffer.311602/#post-2948116

Comment: Just tested it, and it works, thank you!